# How can I prove that $\int_{a}^{b} |f(x)|dx$ defines norm on $C([a,b])$?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I need to show that

$$\parallel f \parallel = \int_{a}^{b} |f(x)|dx$$

is a norm on $C([a,b])$. I need to show that $\|f\|$ meets the properties of a norm:

- positive distance,
- if all elements are zero then the distance is zero,
- the triangle inequality and scalar multiplication.

As a suggestion, the problem suggests using the definition of continuity in order to prove that $\int_{a}^{b} |f(x)|dx>0$ for all $f>0$. I have little to non-existent experience in proofs and analysis and am trying to learn on my own, with little luck. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Indeed notice that continuity ensures $f>0$ on some interval so the lower sum is positive for the right choice of a partition

Comment: I added a picture to my answer that may be helpful.

Comment: If $\int_{a}^{b}|f|dx = 0$, then $0\le\int_{a}^{t}|f|dx \le \int_{a}^{b}|f|dx = 0$ gives $\int_{a}^{t}|f|dx =0$ for all $a\le t \le b$. By the fundamental theorem of Calculus, $|f(t)|=\frac{d}{dt}\int_{a}^{t}|f|dx=0$ follows for all $a \le t \le b$.

Answer (score 2):

I'll leave some hints. For a constant $c$,
$$
\left\Vert cf\right\Vert ={\it \int_{a}^{b}\left|cf(x)\right|dx=\int_{a}^{b}\left|c\right|\left|f(x)\right|dx=\cdots}
$$
The triangle inequality is an application of the triangle inequality on $|\cdot|$:
$$
\left\Vert f+g\right\Vert =\int_{a}^{b}\left|f(x)+g(x)\right|dx\leq\int_{a}^{b}\left|f(x)\right|+\left|g(x)\right|dx=\cdots
$$
Lastly, note that for any $f$, the norm is nonnegative:
$$
\left\Vert f\right\Vert =\int_{a}^{b}\left|f(x)\right|dx\geq0.
$$

---

So the only tough part remaining is to show that if the norm is zero, $|f|$ is the zero function (i.e. $|f(x)|=0$ for all $x$, and hence $f(x)=0$ for all $x$).

**Hint**: start by assuming the negation of the statement, so that you can find a continuous function $|f|$ that is nonzero and has norm zero. Since $|f|$ is continuous, you can find an interval on which $|f|\geq M>0$. Can you figure out the rest?

---

Consider a nonnegative continuous function $|f|$ that takes a positive value somewhere. For example:

[image]

Then we can find $M$ (e.g. $M=0.1$) and an interval $(a,b)$ on which $|f|\geq M$. The integral of the function on this interval is positive, and the norm is at least as large as its integral on this subinterval.

Answer (score 2):

I am also new to analysis like you if almost having $\epsilon$ level of experience in "real analysis". Let $f \in \mathcal{C}[a,b]$ and suppose further that $f \neq 0$, hence there is some $c \in [a,b]$ with $f(c) \neq 0$. If $c = a$, then $f(a) \neq 0$ and since $f$ is countinuous at $x = a$, using definition of continuity at $a$ for $f$ we have: $\epsilon = \dfrac{|f(a)|}{2} > 0, \exists \delta > 0: \forall x \in [a,b], 0 < |x-a| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(a)| < \dfrac{|f(a)|}{2}$, and by the familiar triangular inequality: 
$|f(a)| - |f(x)| \leq |f(x)-f(a)| \Rightarrow |f(a)| - |f(x)| < \dfrac{|f(a)|}{2} \Rightarrow |f(x)| > \dfrac{|f(a)|}{2} > 0$. You can choose the $\delta$ small enough so that $(a, a+\delta) \subseteq [a,b]$. Thus $\displaystyle \int_{a}^b |f(x)|dx \geq \displaystyle \int_{a}^{a+\delta} |f(x)|dx > \displaystyle \int_{a}^{a+\delta} \dfrac{|f(a)|}{2}dx= \dfrac{\delta\cdot |f(a)|}{2} > 0$. The argument also works for $c = b$ or $a < c < b$. Thus the hard part of the proof is taken care of.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I will work through this and report back.